# Google Sheets Find Cell containing date in other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to make a planner, I would like to find the cell in another sheet called 'Main' that matches my cell A2.
The date would be in row 2 of which some are not dates.

I'm just looking to do conditional formatting based on that cell but can't seem to find out how to get the cell

any help would be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the cell in Row 2 of the Main sheet, then you can highlight row 2 in the Main sheet and apply conditional formatting in the Main sheet using this formula:

> =A$1=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$2")

Please note that the above formula assumes that the sheet containing reference date in A2 is named "Sheet1."